# Possibility of fixing corrupt MySQL database

Tags: mysql, backup

Obviously this wouldn't be an issue if there was a backup, but this database started out as just a test.

Soon it started to be used for more important data and then I made a plan to move it to a production environment and set up some type of regular backups.

Currently I have the prod environment set up and was planning on making the move today. But (as luck would have it) when I tried to get into the server where the DB lives I found I had no connectivity. I opened up a console and saw that there were disk errors. I tried to fix these with `fsck` but now, although it boots, I can't login and I see all types of errors during boot.

So as a last resort I tried to use an ubuntu live cd to get in and copy some files to another destination.

I noticed when I copy the files in the MySQL datadir, it can't copy the `ibdata1` or `ib_logfile1`. I get the errors:

```
cp: error reading 'ibdata1': Input/output error
cp: error reading 'ib_logfile1': Input/output error
```

So before I write this off as a loss (and gain valuable experience with the need for backups) I figured I'd check here to see if there is any way to recover the MySQL data.

Comment: Did you stop mysqld before trying to copy the files?

Comment: I was booted into an Ubuntu live cd

Answer (score 1):

"if there is any way to recover the MySQL data." - short answer to this question - it depends on how badly ibdata1 (and rest of important files) are corrupt.

It's a hardware error, IO system call returns `Input/output error`, so ibdata1 is definitely corrupt.

At minimum you need to copy ibdata1, *.ibd and *.frm files. If simple `cp` doesn't succeed copy a files with `dd` ignoring errors.

```
# dd if=/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 of=/some/good/disk/ibdata1  conv=noerror
```

Once you copy all files try to start MySQL with `innodb_force_recovery`. Try all values from 1 to 6 until MySQL starts. If you are lucky and it starts, take `mysqldump`. MySQL may crash in the process. Try to dump individual tables.

```
for d in `mysql -NBe "SHOW DATABASES"`
do
    for t in `mysql -NBe "SHOW TABLES" $d`
    do
        mysqldump --skip-lock-tables $d $t > $d/$t.sql
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then sleep 30; fi
    done
done
```

If MySQL doesn't start - you can upload MySQL datadir in a zip/tar.gz archive on https://recovery.twindb.com/ (DISCLAIMER: I'm the author), it will try to recover the databases and will show you recovered data. (it will ask for a payment if you want to download a dump).

If you don't feel comfortable uploading your data google `undrop-for-innodb` (DISCLAIMER: I'm the author) and use https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/ as a guide.

Percona's data recovery toolkit will also work (https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb) (keep in mind `stream_parser` == `page_parser`, `c_parser` == `constraints_parser`). If you use Percona's toolkit make sure you use the latest revision from the trunk (`bzr branch lp:percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb`). Do not use version 0.5 available from downloads!

Answer (score 0):

To enable auto recovery MySQL needs `innodb_force_recovery` option to be enabled, which forces InnoDB to start up while preventing background operations from running, so that you can dump your tables.

To do this, open `my.cnf` and add the following line to the `[mysqld]` section:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery=1
service mysql restart
```

You should start from `innodb_force_recovery=1`, save the changes to `my.cnf` file, and then restart the MySQL server using the appropriate command for your operating system.

If you are able to dump your tables with an `innodb_force_recovery` value of 3 or less, then you are relatively safe. In many cases you will have to go up to 4 and as you already know that can corrupt data.

Once you are able to start your database, type the following command to export all of the databases to the `databases.sql` file:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --add-drop-database --add-drop-table > dump.sql
```

Start mysql, and then try to drop the affected database or databases using the `DROP DATABASE` command. If MySQL is unable to drop a database, you can delete it manually using the steps below after you stop the MySQL server.